# How do I activate "snap to increment" in perspective and camera mode?

Tags: 3d-view, snapping

I thought snap to increment and absolute grid snap were only available in orthographic view, but somehow I managed to activate it in a viewport in perspective mode. How did I do that?"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but all snapping options are available for (almost) all "modes" via the magnet icon at the top center of the viewport, and the corresponding dropdown menu to the right of it.

Comment: If it wasn't available in Perspective view, how would you see what you were doing when Snap to Grid was active? :^)

Comment: @JohnEason Since his assumption was snapping were not available in perspective view, there would be no need to see what you do... or do you think it's impossible to see it in orthographic view? I don't get what you want to say :D

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Well he said that he'd "somehow managed to activate it in Perspective view" so I was just pointing out that  there wouldn't be much point in having a "Snap to Grid" option at all if it wasn't available in Perspective view. Probably a badly constructed sentence on my part! :^)

Comment: I use 3 view ports, one in orthographic in X and Z axis, one in orthographic in Y and Z axis and one in perspective view. That's how I used to use snap to grid in perspective mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized my mistake.

I didn't realize that I had set a different grid unit in the viewport in perspective mode, so when I moved something there, it moved a lot. I had .0025m in orthographic and .025 in perspective. You have to use the same grid unit on all viewports for snap to grid to work correctly